# Best Practice to save Json on SQL Database

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

I'm going to save a Json on the SQL Database. I'm thinking to create a table with two columns.

Table (id, JsonData)
and the json could be like this

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "url": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I will covert the json data to String and save it on the database and retrieve this String and convert back to json.
Can anyone suggest me a best way to save and retrieve the JsonData?

Comment: I think you mean two columns--your JSON seems to have 3 rows worth of data.  And better in what way?

Comment: yes, I' sorry two columns

Comment: If you want useable data, parse the json and store it in a normalized database.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sqlite for example

Comment: And better how?  If your question is just for general advice, it's not really a fit for this site, which is more oriented towards questions with definitive answers.

Comment: I update the question, maybe now it is better to understand what I'm looking for

Comment: @Kev thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is just save the json string into the database and later use javascript to get the json object this way:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks the String works for me now!.

Comment: Me too thanks for the input